# Loop through files using "" instead of Dir

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Upon understanding of `Dir` function:  `Dir [( path [, attributes ] ) ]`
**[Path]** is optional and **if it is not found**, the DIR function will return a zero-length string.
I replaced `StrFile = Dir` with `StrFile = ""` on the below code, and it just debug.printed only one file on my directory.

So, What is the meaning of `StrFile = Dir`?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("c:\testfolder\*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print StrFile
        StrFile = ""
    Loop
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Upon reading the documentation @[Dir function (Visual Basic for Applications)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) it seems initial call to Dir

```
StrFile = Dir("c:\testfolder\*")
```

will return the first file that matches the pathname. Since there's at least one file while loop is entered and subsequent calls to Dir without argument returns additional filenames that match filepath. This is until no more filenames match and Dir returns "" to the StrFile and breaks the while loop.

I believe when you set

```
StrFile = ""
```

It skips the fetching of additional filenames that match filepath and only the first file that matches is printed...